# Text shadow filter in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

Text shadow is not supported in IE 9.

So I use this filter. It apply text shadow but also apply a black dotted line with shadow.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(direction=135, color=#FFFFFF, Strength=3);
```

How can I remove this black dots?

You can visit it [on-line](http://pacmangroup.com/test/).

Comment: *Which version(s) of IE?

Answer (score 0):

Creating shadows in IE is also possible using JQuery: [Text-shadow in IE with jQuery](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/javascript/text-shadow-in-ie-with-jquery/) (At all a better solution than filters in my opinion.)

Answer (score 0):

There is [the `Glow` filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532995%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is *sort of* similar to `text-shadow`. Might be worth a try:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(color=#ffffff, strength=3);
```